# sql query to display the balances of two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Example

**table1** considered as purchasing

```
 barcode       articleno      Description      size
 0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7
 10125         500845-400     nikeshoes        8
 0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7
 0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7
 1254          125456-700     nikeshoes        12
```

**Table2**  considered as trasfering stock

```
 barcode       articleno      Description      size
 0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7 
 10125         500845-400     nikeshoes        8
```

**OUTPUT :** balace stocks

```
 barcode       articleno      Description      size
 0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7 
 0101010       500845-400     nike shoes       7 
  1254         125456-700     nikeshoes        12
```

Comment: Do you have any other columns, such as an `id`?  The rows are identical.  Also, would it be sufficient to just have a count of "2" rather than two separate rows?

Comment: ya i have another column id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this.  The idea is to remove `n` rows from the first table for a given barcode/size combination (I'm assuming that is the unique identifier for rows).  The value of `n` is the number of rows in the second table.

The following query does this by removing the first `n` rows based on `id`.  It filters out the rows where the number of preceding ids is less than count:

```
select p.*
from purchasing p left outer join
     (select barcode, size, count(*) as cnt
      from transfers t
      group by barcode, size
     ) bc
     on p.barcode = bc.barcode and p.size = bc.size
where coalesce(cnt, 0) < (select count(*)
                          from purchasing p2
                          where p2.barcode = p.barcode and
                                p2.size = p.size and
                                p2.id <= p.id
                         );
```

Comment: i am getting output four rows  its should be three rows